# Guess the Number Game Python - Final Step of Repeating The Function, But Not From The Very Beginning

Tags: python

So my question is: How do I manage to repeat this function not from the beginnigng, but from game_over = False on, so as to avoid it choosing a random number again, resetting difficulty mode and used lives, etc.

Everything else seems to work, but unfortunately, if I were to call the function again after game_over = True, then it would naturally start the function from the beginning...

```
from art import logo
import random 
from replit import clear

def guess_the_number():
  guess_number = random.choice(range(1, 101))
    
  print(f"This is a cheat! Number is: {guess_number}")
  print(logo)
  print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")
  print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100...Can you guess it?")

  game_difficulty = input("Chooce a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard': ")
  lives = 0
  if game_difficulty == "easy":
    lives = 10
    print(f"You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number")
    user_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
  elif game_difficulty == "hard": 
    lives = 5
    print(f"You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
    user_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))

  game_over = False
  while not game_over:
    lives = 10
    if user_guess == guess_number:
      game_over = True
      print("You won!")
      again = input("Do you want to play again? Type 'y' or 'n': ")
      if again == "y":
        clear()
        guess_the_number()
    if user_guess != guess_number:
      lives -= 1
    if lives == 0:
      game_over = True
      print("You lost.")
      again = input("Do you want to play again? Type 'y' or 'n': ")
      if again == "y":
        clear()
        guess_the_number()
 
    if user_guess < guess_number:
      print("Too low.")
      print("Guess again.")
      print(f"You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
      user_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
    else:
      print("Too high.")
      print("Guess again.")
      print(f"You have {lives} attempts remaining to guess the number.")
      user_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))

        
guess_the_number()
```

Comment: Move the stuff you don't want repeated out of the function.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Though I have another issue now: When the if statement condition for "win"  or "lose" is met in the while loop, it prints the "You won" or "you lost" message as many times as guesses were made.